# Using Bundler along with preinstalled gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

So I've got `thin` installed the old fashioned way:

```
gem install thin
```

I put an app on the server and installed all of its required gems via bundler:

```
bundle install
```

But, when I tried to start the app with `thin start`, it can't find any of the bundler-installed gems since they're not installed in the default gems directory.

My question is: how do I make this work? Do I need to install `thin` via bundler as well? Will that still set up the `thin` executable in `/usr/bin` so I can start it from the command line like normal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Bundler has a little setup method that gets all require paths ready so that the ones bundler itself installed are available just like regular gems:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
require 'sequel'
```

In this case `sequel` was installed with bundler, not rubygems. So calling it without the `Bundle.setup` call first would not work. But with `Bundle.setup`, the location of all the bundler-installed gems is added to the load path so ruby can find them. Easy!